# Google Cloud Function error deploying error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hello I have a python cloud function :

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from google.cloud import storage
import os

api_key = os.environ['API_KEY']
url = f'https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/scores/json/TeamSeasonStats/2022?key=${api_key}'

def export_data(url):
    response = requests.get(url)  # Make a GET request to the URL
    print(response)
    payload = response.json() # Parse `response.text` into JSON

    # Use the flatsplode package to quickly turn the JSON response to a DF
    new_list = pd.DataFrame(list(payload))

    # Convert your df to str: it is straightforward, just do not provide
    # any value for the first param path_or_buf
    csv_str = new_list.to_csv()

    # Then, upload it to cloud storage
    def upload_blob(bucket_name, data, destination_blob_name):

        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
        # Note the use of upload_from_string here. Please, provide
        # the appropriate content type if you wish
        blob.upload_from_string(data, content_type='text/csv')

    upload_blob('basketball_api_data', csv_str, 'data-' + str(datetime.date.today()) + '.csv')

export_data(url)
```

Its basically getting Basketball API Data: however I am getting errors deploying this
my requirements.txt looks like this :

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version
google-cloud-storage
pandas
requests
datetime
os
google.cloud
```

Am I writing my cloud function in a wrong way? What am I doing wrong to cause error deploying this to GCF?

This is my error: [image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Sorry I uploaded the error and dont understand what the error is

Comment: Please copy and paste the error as text, that's nearly impossible to read

Comment: There's usually an option in the Console to go to the full Cloud Logging explorer. This will also contain the full log details rather than the summary you've image copied. You can copy and paste the text from Cloud Logging.

Comment: Reviewing your code, Cloud Functions expects an HTTP handler. Your code doesn't conform to the expected format. See: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python

Comment: You need to stick to the Cloud Functions functions signature. It's not your case, so it doesn't work. Have a look to the documentation and the quickstart